# Create a column Counting the consecutive True values on multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Let df be a dataframe of boolean values with a two column index. I want to calculate the value for every id. For example, this is how it would look on this specific case.

```
              value   consecutive 
    id  Week           
     1  1     True     1
     1  2     True     2   
     1  3     False    0      
     1  4     True     1
     1  5     True     2
     2  1     False    0
     2  2     False    0
     2  3     True     1
```

**This is my solution**:

```
def func(id,week):
    M = df.loc[id]
    M= df.loc[id][:week+1]

    consecutive_list = list()
    S=0
    for index,row in M.iterrows():
        if row['value']:
            S+=1
        else:
            S=0
        consecutive_list.append(S)
    return consecutive_list[-1]
```

Then we generate the column "consecutive" as a list on the following way:

```
Consecutive_list = list()
for k in df.index:
    id = k[0]
    week=k[1]
    Consecutive_list.append(func(id,week))

df['consecutive'] = Consecutive_list
```

I would like to know if there is a more Pythonic way to do this.

EDIT: I wrote the "consecutive" column in order to show what I expect this to be.

Comment: what's the expected output? you already have column named `consecutive` and you're overwriting it with a different list, so I'm a bit confused here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the consecutive column to the df, this should work:

```
df.assign(consecutive = df['value'].groupby(df['value'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).cumsum())
```

Output:

```
     value  consecutive
1 a   True            1
  b   True            2
2 a  False            0
  b   True            1
3 a   True            2
  b  False            0
4 a  False            0
  b   True            1
```

Comment: This does not reset after finishing the first level of the multi index.